# Is there ambiguity in "by each" in this context?

Tags: ambiguity, quantifiers, context

The sentence:

> "Find all malls that have been visited by each student attending Wolf
> Secondary School"

I've recently encountered a question like this on a Computer Science test and interpretted it as so:

> Return a list of malls, where each mall was visited by at least 1 student attending Wolf Secondary School.

But the "correct" way to answer the question was:

> Return a list of malls, where each mall must has been visited by every single
> student attending Wolf Secondary School.

I'm curious to if there's any ambiguity to the original question and if my interpretation was reasonable/justifiable.

Comment: So basically you have to enlist all those malls that have been visited by each student of the mentioned school. This means a given student might have visited any given number of malls between 0,  and, say 10. I don't see what is the problem with the sentence as it's given.

Comment: In casual terms, your interpretation is reasonable, but better said as *visited by a student*.

Comment: @Pkjmm to clarify, you're saying my interpretation was indeed incorrect?

Comment: To me, the most reasonable interpretation of the original question is *make n lists of malls where n is the number of students.  Each of the n lists will correspond to a single student and will contain one entry per mall visited by that student.*

Comment: The search wants to restrict results to those malls that all students visited. Not altogether, of course, but each student who visited all those malls. Any mall that did not get visited by each student does not count, no matter how many visits it got. That is why "visited by at least 1 student" does not match the original in intent, and will return a number probably too large.

Comment: Given a mall that was visited by a single student Ask yourself, “Was this mall visited by each student”  Answer: No.